# How to get the table immediately previous to current table row

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

Say I get a list of  rows like this

```
    var table_stop_rows = (from r in doc.Descendants("TR").Cast<HtmlNode>()
                      where r.Attributes["name"]?.Value == "laneStop"
                      select r).ToList();
```

Now, for each of those "laneStop" rows, I want to refer back to the smaller table containing the "shipment_number" field and read its corresponding node value, eg "abc_123_florida-4".  However, I cant simply get a list of all rows where there is a shipment_number, each one has to be in a table that precedes the "laneStop" row in the row collection I'm getting.

I suppose my question then is - if I have a collection of rows, can I then use an xpath statement relative to each row to get back to this shipment_number field in the table preceding?

Here is the html doc, note there would be dozens of these "table pairs".  Since I can't control the structure of these files, I need a way to extract the data from the existing structure

[image]

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Date</td>
                                                <td>11/15/2019</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>shipment number</td>
                                                <td>abc_123_florida-45</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Departure time:</td>
                                                <td>0430</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Time arrival</td>
                                                <td>1715</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>customer</td>
                                                <td>bob smith</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>box type</td>
                                                <td>square</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr name="laneStop">
                                <td>box1</td>
                                <td>23.45</td>
                                <td>lane1</td>
                                <td>south</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr name="laneStop">
                                <td>box2</td>
                                <td>17.14</td>
                                <td>lane1</td>
                                <td>south</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr name="laneStop">
                                <td>box3</td>
                                <td>17.18</td>
                                <td>lane1</td>
                                <td>north</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr name="laneStop">
                                <td>box2</td>
                                <td>199.14</td>
                                <td>lane1</td>
                                <td>west</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>   
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath expression:

```
(//tr[@name="laneStop"]/ancestor::table/preceding-sibling::table//tr[2]/td[2])[1]
```